# Virtual hosts not working on MAMP

Tags: apache, mamp, virtualhost

I am running into virtual hosts setup issues on MAMP. Here is my vhosts config

```html
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *>
        ServerName dev.local.com
 DocumentRoot “/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/local”
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
        DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
        ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my hosts file

```html
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       dev.local.com
```

now when visiting localhost and dev.local.com both are pointing to index of local directory. I tried various config setting in vhosts file but none is working. I am on MacBook Pro 10.10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changed the hosts file like this -

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.local.com
    DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/local
    ServerAlias dev.local.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: For anyone still looking. According to [this link](http://www.imore.com/how-edit-your-macs-hosts-file-and-why-you-would-want) you could also try clearing the DNS cache: `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder return`

Comment: @user6166 could you please take a look my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52510110/virtual-host-with-mamp 
I have a problem when I creating with Vhost.

Answer (score 15):

I didn't find any of the answers useful, so **if other suggestions don't work for you:**

Consider that the **virtual hosts** need to be **correctly enabled/included** by uncommenting

`Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in **C:\MAMP\conf\apache\httpd.conf** and **NOT** in C:\MAMP\bin\apache\conf or C:\MAMP\bin\apache\conf\original .

There're multiple locations that have MAMP configuration, make sure to uncomment that line in the **correctly located file**.

Comment: After a MAMP upgrade, the line was indeed commented in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf`.

Answer (score 12):

When I first test virtual host (example.dev) I added two slightly different index.php files its directry and to localhost directory (/htdocs). My virtual host would redirect to locahost, I would know because the index.php would be the one in /htdocs. Similar to what user6166 said, I changed the code below to match the 8888 and it worked! I test example.dev:8888 and it works.

```
 NameVirtualHost *:8888

<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ServerName dev.local.com
    DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/local
    ServerAlias dev.local.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8888>
    DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Then to remove 8888 change above back to 80 and MAMP preferences to:

```
Apache Port:80
Nginx Port:8888
mySQL Port:3306
```

Then inside httpd.conf change below to 80:

```
Listen 8888
ServerName localhost:8888
```

Hope that helps someone, it definely fixed my problem!

Comment: This actually worked for me. Should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Enable virtual host in the right httpd.conf
Open MAMP > File > Edit template > Apache > httpd.conf

edit or add:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

[edit mamp httpd.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sC9u.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Try to configure MAMP ports by this way:

1. MAMP
2. Preferences
3. Ports
4. Apache port: 80
   Nginx port: 8888

[image: MAMP ports confi guration]

I've had the same port values and after configurating it started working.

Comment: This worked for me in Mac OS Sonoma. Nothing else was working! Thanks!

Comment: This work for me too, macOS Sonoma 14.2.1 & MAMP Version 6.8. Thank you @Dmitriy Korytnyi

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with **MAMP Pro 5** (after updating from version 4). One of my custom host *with aliases* was returning a 404 NOT FOUND error.

After a LONG troubleshoot, make sure to add the domain in the alias list.

**MAMP 4**

host:

```
test.co
```

alias:

```
sub.test.co
```

**Becomes in MAMP 5:**

host:

```
test.co
```

alias:

```
sub.test.co
test.co
```

Hope they'll get that fixed and that it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Open the main Apache configuration file, **httpd.conf**, which is located at

> Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf

and Remove the hash (pound) sign from the beginning of the line that begins with Include:

## Virtual Hosts

```
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an apache expert. But I had the same problem. I think my DNS doesn't resolve my URL.
When I `ping exampl.dev` everything looks fine, but when I enter example.dev in the browser I get an error. I always have to add http:// in front of the url.