# How can I change the MAMP URL structure on Mac?

Tags: macos, url, localhost, mamp

Currently typing "localhost" into my browser displays a list of projects, all good... I can even do "localhost/mysite" however and I know this is slightly pedantic, but how can I convert this to "localhost.mysite" or for example "projects.local"?

I've attempted editing the hosts files but I'm not having much luck.

httpd.vhosts.conf file contents:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot “/Users/grant/Sites/mysite/"
ServerName mydomainname.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this question: [Virtual hosts not working on MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885815/virtual-hosts-not-working-on-mamp).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the PRO version does just provide a GUI, virtualhosts are possible for with the standard version.