# Virtual Host with MAMP

Tags: drupal, mamp, virtualhost, drupal-8, vhosts

I installed Drupal 8 with MAMP. 
My MAMP preference number for **Apache Port : 80 , Nginx Port: 80  and MySQL Port: 8889**

In ***etc/hosts*** file, I add
 `127.0.0.1       mmcast.test`

In httpd.conf file,

```
Listen 80
```

and uncomment the following line.

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

In **httpd-vhosts.conf** file,

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mmcast.test
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mmcast"
</VirtualHost>
```

When I call the site, I type **mmcast.test:8888** and also try with **mmcast.test:80**. 
 However, nothing works! :( 
Could someone help me please? 
 I've been trying this problem and still cannot solve.

Comment: Have you tried to access your url mmcast.test without port i.e http://mmcast.test ?

Comment: Could happen to anyone, but have you restarted MAMP after making these changes? Also, define "nothing works". What error are you getting?

Comment: Are you sure that 127.0.0.1 is correct ip address? Try visiting site over ip address or pinging ip address.

Comment: @Ritesh, Yes. I tried without port. It shows "The requested URL / was not found on this server." bro.

Comment: @TolgaOzses, bro whatever I make changes, I always restart MAMP.  When I open the site without port or with 8888 or with 80. All are not working

Comment: what is the output of localhost/mmcast?

Answer (score 0):

in httpd.conf file

ServerName localhost:8888

has to be changed to

ServerName localhost:80

Comment: It may resolve the issue but a little explanation to the answer in proper format make it more usable.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8 you need different settings for creating virtual host.

Here is the snippet that needs to be added for virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:8888>
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site-name/web"
  ServerName local.site-name.com
  <Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site-name/web/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So I access my local site as

```
local.site-name.com:8888
```

I have used default port, which is 8888. So above snippet is according to it.

You can refer this link from [Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/111238) as well.