# Virtual Host not working on Mac OS (MAMP)

Tags: macos, apache, mamp

OS: Mac OS
Mamp 6.6 version

The virtual host is not working, when I open the host I get an error:

> Not Found
> The requested URL was not found on this server.

looked at a lot of articles on topic of installing virtual hosts and it seems that I did everything right

My hosts file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpxFZ.png)

The virtual hosts file is included in configuration file /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

My httpd-vhost-conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName localhost
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
    DocumentRoot "/Users/danilbondarev/Projects/php"
    <Directory "/Users/danilbondarev/Projects/php">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName localhost
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
    DocumentRoot "/Users/danilbondarev/Projects/php/hybrid-main"
    <Directory "/Users/danilbondarev/Projects/php/hybrid-main">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes execCGI
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow From All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Mamp->Preferences->Server->Document Root:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwJ1N.png)

Error screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ7EP.png)

I want to note: I always restart apache and MAMP when I make any changes to the config files. I also tried to give directories permissions for Apache and it didn't help, although obviously this wasn't the problem

Tried these solutions:
[Virtual hosts not working on MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885815/virtual-hosts-not-working-on-mamp)
[MAMP setting virtual host does not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58451672/mamp-setting-virtual-host-does-not-working)